# Using custom meta_query with relation not working as expected

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I am trying to create a query to pull future events only. It was working great until the client requested the ability to add date ranges--so the event will either have a start date only, OR a start date and an end date. I need to build a query that pulls events events that has a start date in the future OR an end date in the future. This does not work as expected and pulls all events; and the order of what's pulled seems random, despite setting orderby to meta_value. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
    function get_upcoming_events($num) {
    $today =  gmdate('Y-m-d', time()-28800);

    $args = array(
        'meta_key'          => 'event_date',
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'    => $num,
        'post_type'         => 'events',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation'=>'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'event_date',
                'type' => 'DATE',
                'value' => $today,
                'compare' => '>=' 
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'end_date',
                'type' => 'DATE',
                'value' => $today,
                'compare' => '>=' 
            )
        )
    );

    if ( isset( $data[ 'taxonomy' ]) ) {
        $args[ 'tax_query' ] = array();
        $args[ 'tax_query' ][0] = array(
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'taxonomy'  => 'event-type',
            'terms'     => 'general'
        );
    }
    $myquery = new WP_Query( $args );
    return $myquery;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You're getting all the posts because you set `'meta_key' => 'event_date'`.

This is equivalent to adding another subquery into 'meta_query' that says "get me all posts which have an event_date custom field, with *any* value OR that have even_date to $today etc.".

PS: There are many event plugins out there that have already figured all this stuff out. Give them a try or at least look at their code.

Comment: I just posted a solution here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/128038/21163